# Smooth rollout with keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I have recently discovered the css3 keyframes and I want to put in practice the method with a hover state. Unfortunately, I note the rollout state isn't smooth at all and come back straight to the first frame.

Is there any way to make the rollout smoother ?

Here's my work : [http://jsfiddle.net/WYbyJ](http://jsfiddle.net/WYbyJ/)

Thanks a lot

HTML :

```
<div></div>
```

CSS :

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
div:hover{
    animation:mymove .8s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:mymove .8s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove{
    0%, 100% {
        width:100px;
    }
    50% {
        width:120px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove{
    0%, 100% {
        width:100px;
    }
    50% {
        width:120px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'smoother'? Maybe you can fine tune the animation with the duration and [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).

Comment: By smoother, I mean I would like an .8s rollout going to the first frame. Currently, when you you move your mouse out of the div, the rollout is rough